# Is solvedstack.com Affiliated With Stack Exchange?

Tags: discussion

Lately I've noticed lots of search results coming up on the domain http://solvedstack.com/.  They appear to be [solved] questions from https://stackoverflow.com/  The questions and answers are identical, and even the user pictures seem to be copied over.

Is this a legitimate affiliate of Stack Exchange that is intended to provide additional value?

Comment: It might be a scraper, but if it isn't, feel free to edit and inform me/the closers.

Comment: @Patrick - Not a dup or not a legitimate affiliate?

Comment: Just another scraper trying to collect some crumbs of traffic from Stack Overflow.

Comment: Value added: [SOLVED] in the title attribute on every page.